# The screen problem

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hardware, display, software

Hardware specs: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012); 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5 processor;
                4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3; Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB
Software specs: Mac OS-X yosemite 10.10.3;
Some part of my screen blinks and looks like that laptop is hanged but actually its only screen problem. But i don't know whether it is hardware problem and software problem. I tried to close all the applications running to check whether it is caused by a software or 3rd party app. But that was not the case. I captured a video of this small error. Sometimes the screen gets a little messy. BUT EVERYTHING STARTS LIKE THIS VIDEO LINK IN THE DESCRIPTION https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83BFdS489w1TUtMS0VZSDE1OWs/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone suggest what should i do?

Comment: It is broken alright. did you run the Apple Hardware test ? does it do it in Safe mode. Does it do it if you log in as different user ?

Comment: Can this problem be resolved using PRAM reset?

Comment: You can try, but I doubt it.

Comment: Does Apple Hardware test solve the problems or does it gives only the results?

Comment: Result only, it is not a repair system. If you want to try to repair software then reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me that looks like possible hardware problem (the GPU).

You can try the Safe mode to see if the problem persist.

Also you can try and log in as different user.

You can reset the PRAM, and run the Apple Hardware test.

Last not least you can reinstall the OS.

All above will test for software problems.

There is one hardware test you can do and it is to connect external monitor (or TV), that will tell you if it is your LCD screen or the GPU.